# I got a white screen with vertical lines on it when I booted my Raspberry Pi

Tags: display, touchscreen

I am using a Raspberry Pi Model B+ with an Adafruit touch screen monitor.  When I booted, I got a display that looks like this:

[image: a]

[image: a]

The vertical lines are red, green, and blue, and the screen seems to draw more of them as time goes on.  I've searched for my problem, and although I found many questions on a white screen, I found no questions on a white screen with lines on it.

**Additional information:**

The Power Good light on the monitor is on, and the Touch light is flashing.  The Display Good light is not on.

I am using a screen bought in 2016 with a Raspberry Pi bought in 2014.  The Micro-SD card is also from 2014 and it came preloaded with the OS.  It is possible that the software is out of date.

I dropped some of the boxes on the floor at one point, but they were enclosed in bubble wrap and other protective packaging at the time, so I don't think that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In no case should a working LCD display such lines. Double check your connectors, try another HDMI cable if you have one, then RMA the display to the vendor while you still can.

If you can't, you may want to look up how to dispose of electronic waste in your community.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a monitor issue. Try using the monitor on a desktop. If not, format the SD and reinstall rasbian. If that doesn't fix it then it is probably a hardware issue.

Comment: What is "the Sim"? Is that what you kids call an SD card these days?

Comment: Sorry, I posted this really tired. Yes I mean SD.

Comment: No problem, I was in a joking mood. BTW, you can edit your answer any time you want, if you want to fix or update something.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's a broken display. I've seen this happen on many laptops' displays when they were dropped. It may be fixable, but know that the problem is most likely not the Raspberry Pi or the microSD card, it is the display.